# delaying job queue on lumen

Tags: lumen, laravel-7

I have a project on Lumen 7 which includes a lot of queues but I can't get to delay the job.

This is how I dispatch a job:

```
dispatch(new NotifyJob($user, $template));
```

but when I add this

```
dispatch(new NotifyJob($user, $template))->delay(now()->addMinutes(10));
```

I get this error

```
"Call to undefined method Laravel\\Lumen\\Bus\\PendingDispatch::delay()"
```

And doing this
`EmailJob::dispatch($user, $template);`
gives me `Undefined method dispatch`

I just can't get the delay to work.

Comment: Can you show how you defined your `EmailJob` class?  and Lumen is using a different Bus then the one that comes with Laravel so it does not have `delay` on the `PendingDispatch` it seems

Answer (score 6):

You can use the "Queue" facade.

for example:

```
Queue::later(Carbon::now()->addMinutes(10),new GetCityInfoDelay());
```

Comment: Thanks It works, This is not mentioned in official page https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues