# Can not delay a queue job in Lumen (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I'm developing an API using Lumen framework based on Laravel.

I've created a job that store some assets in my product interface management. Due to some API limits, I can not make more than 500 api calls in an hour, so I thought to create multiple job scheduled over several hours.

For that I found that Laravel allows to do it with the `delay` method, I followed the doc, however I get an exception when I go to execute my code

```
StoreAssetsJob::dispatch($params['ids'])->delay(Carbon::now()->addHours(1));
```

And the error

```
Error: Call to undefined method App\\Jobs\\StoreAssetsJob::dispatch()
```

My job

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use App\Helpers\ArrayToObjectHelper;

/**
 * This job execute assets import to DAM
 */
class StoreAssetsJob extends Job
{

    private array $identifiers;
    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(array $identifiers)
    {
        $this->identifiers = $identifiers;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    { }
}
```

Job class

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;


abstract class Job implements ShouldQueue
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Queueable Jobs
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This job base class provides a central location to place any logic that
    | is shared across all of your jobs. The trait included with the class
    | provides access to the "queueOn" and "delay" queue helper methods.
    |
    */

    use InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the contents of your `StoreAssetsJob.php` class? Make sure it matches the example documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues#class-structure. For some reason, `dispatch()` is not available on that Class, as evident by your error message.

Comment: @TimLewis I edited the question and I truncated the handle method to hide my code

Comment: Looks like you're missing `use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;` and `use Dispatchable;` on your `Job.php` class  (Sidenote; never used Lumen, assuming it's mostly equivalent to base Laravel's implementation)

Comment: Dispatchable class does not exsits in Lumen projects

Comment: Hmm, you are correct! Looks like you can do it a different way, as outlined here: https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues. `dispatch(new StoreAssetsJob)` or `Queue::push(new StoreAssetsJob)`

Comment: Yeah it is my new path, I found this solution, I'll test it :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64384503/delaying-job-queue-on-lumen

Comment: Nice! Yeah, that question/answer looks like it would be the next logical step to solving you issue. Hopefully that works for you! Cheers!

Comment: I can not found path of the Queue facade

Comment: Found it : illuminate\contracts\Queue\Queue